# htaccess rewriteRule to uri with repeated pattern

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to redirect "www.mydomain.com/pattern/pattern/value" to "www.mydomain.com/pattern/value" ?
Using:

```
RewriteRule ^pattern/(.*) /$1 [l,r,qsa]
```

Redirects to: www.mydomain.com/value, missing the pattern directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks anubhava on pointing me to the right direction:
This is my final code

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)            search.php?q=$1 [qsa]
RewriteRule ^search/images/(.*)     images/$1
RewriteRule ^search/css/(.*)        css/$1
RewriteRule ^search/search/(.*)     /search/$1?s [l,r]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search/(.*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRINg} !^s$
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)            /$1 [l,r]
```

I'm adding the ?s QUERY_STRING only in case of double pattern, to keep it as clean as possible.
The HTTP_REFERER is used to apply the rule only if the link comes from the page with the query result.

Answer (score 0):

It is because rule is executing twice due to this pattern: `^pattern/(.*)`

1. It matches `/pattern/pattern/value` and redirects to `/pattern/value`
2. It matches `/pattern/value` again and redirect to `/value`

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.+)$ /$1?r [L,R]
```

Comment: That works to redirect "/pattern/pattern/value" to "/pattern/value", but it should also works to redirect "/pattern/value" to "/value".
What I need is to remove the first "pattern" from the URL, not the second, as in your example. Can you help me with that?

Comment: My rule is ONLY removing 1st pattern since 2nd pattern is part of `$1` that is used again on right hand side.

Comment: Then I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
www.mydomain.com/pattern/val 
is not redirecting to
www.mydomain.com/val

Comment: But I thought you don't want `/value` as the final URI. Is it not?

Comment: If "/pattern/pattern/val" I want "/pattern/val".
If "/pattern/val" I want "/val".
Which means I want everything after the first "/pattern"

Comment: As I wrote it can be done but same rule will fire 2nd time and will make it `/value`. Can you allow a query string to be appended in resulting URI so that redirect doesn't happen 2nd time.

Comment: I can find other ways to solve redirect and navigation issues on my project, but I'm trying an approach using htacess.
The whole scenario is something like this:
I perform a database search that is triggered by: /search/keyword
Any link triggered from this URL will try to find a /search dir, even a new search, that will post do /search/search/keyword.
I know I could use href="/etc" and <form action="/search">, but I have the same project running on different servers. One some environments it is on the root directory, on others it is not.

Comment: Sorry man, messed with my css and image folder mapping. This was my first attempt before opening this post:
`RewriteRule ^search/images/(.*)  images/$1
RewriteRule ^search/css/(.*)  css/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} search/(.*)
RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /$1 [l,r,qsa]
`

Comment: ok, navigation is behaving as expected now. Even writing redirect like this: `RewriteRule ^search/(.*) /$1?r [l,r,qsa]`.
But is the only way to do it evaluating empty QUERY_STRING? Not possible without ?r. After all, the purpose to use redirect is to work with more elegant URLs.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: Going to bed now so last comment. Since you have this senate requirement of string always the first segment from URL that's why we had to use query string route to prevent looping.